# Finding a closed-form solution or a better approximation to a function in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, approximation

I have the following equation:
$$f(L) = \left\lfloor{\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{L-1}\left\lfloor n+300\times2^{n/7}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor$$ where $1\leq L \leq 99$

My goal is to find a closed-form solution for this equation(if one exists) or an approximation.
I tried

```
f[L_] := Floor (0.25 *
    Sum[Floor (n + 300*Power[2, n/7]), {n, 1, L - 1}])
FullSimplify[f[L], L >= 1 && L <= 99]
```

In Mathematica

Output:

```
Floor^2 (-795.534 + 720.534 2^(L/7) + (-0.125 + 0.125 L) L)
```

However this seems to only give me an approximation because the output is off by up to 15 (compared to the original equation) also i was confused about what Floor^2 meant so when doing the tests i just assumed it referred to the Floor function.

Are there functions in Mathematica that i can use to find a closed-form solution or a better approximation for this equation? I also tried `Simplify` and `FindFormula` but both of them had a far larger error margin compared to using `FullSimplify`

Edit: after fixing the mistake(had to use square brackets instead of paranthesis)

```
f[L_]:=Floor[1/4*Sum[Floor[n+300*Power[2,n/7]],{n,1,L-1}]];
```

```
FullSimplify[f[L]]
```

outputs the following(took a pic as it wouldn't let me copy properly)
[image]

Which is not what im after either (I need a closed-form solution)

Comment: If I compare `Floor[-795.534 + 720.534* 2^(L/7) + (-0.125 + 0.125 L) L]` to the function you start with it is off by 15 for the last few points, which is only an error of 1.1*^-6. In fact, the error is worse when the function is only 'off' by 1 for low values of `L`. Depending on what you need this for, I'd say that's a pretty good approximation. I don't think there's any reason to suspect a "closed form" solution is available for this particular expression.

Comment: For what it's worth, your expression is a finite sum as long as `L` isn't infinity, so I'd call it closed form. I assume because you're asking for a closed form you mean something more restrictive, which you might need to specify.

Comment: I have better approximation ,but output is off by up to 3. :)

Comment: it is a pretty good approximation indeed, however i need it to be less than 1(if it is even possible, but im starting to think it's not)
Of course i can just compute the values once and store them in a table however i was just curious whether it was possible to compute without iterating from 1 to L - 1.

@MariuszIwaniuk just curious tho, what's the better approximation?
Edit: now that u edited ur comment and said it is only off by up to 3, i am even more curious.

Comment: `f[L_]:=Floor[(75 (-2^(1/7) + 2^(L/7)))/(-1 + 2^(1/7)) + 1000/8071*(-1 + L) L]`

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a really good approximation, even amazing I'd say, for L = 300 it is only off by 67

Comment: This is a known sequence given at https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C83%2C174%2C276&language=english&go=Search.  But it lists no closed-form or approximation.

Comment: But ***why*** is this a known sequence?

Comment: i wouldn't really say it's 'known' but yeah this is the minimum xp required for a given level formula from the game runescape

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know "why" and still have no idea about "why" even given the OEIS blurb on this sequence:  "Concerning the popular MMORPG "Runescape" by JAGeX corporation, this sequence gives the number of experience points needed for a given level in a skill."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems good:

```
f2[L_] := 
 Floor[
  -((75 (2^(1/7) - 2^(L/7)))/(-1 + 2^(1/7))) - 
   (14498 L)/63125 + 
   L^2/8];
```

Comparison:

```
tab = Table[f[L] - f2[L], {L, 1000}];
ListPlot[tab, GridLines -> {{}, MinMax@tab}]
```

[image]

```
(* takes a while - did something else, didn't time it *)
tab = Table[f[L] - f2[L], {L, 10, 10000, 10}];
ListPlot[tab,
 GridLines -> {{}, MinMax@tab}, DataRange -> {10, 10000}]
```

[image]

*Update — A brief explanation:*

The function is equal to the floor of
$$\frac{L^2}{8}-\frac{L}{8}-\frac{75
   \left(\sqrt[7]{2}-2^{L/7}\right)}{\sqrt[7]{2}-1} - \alpha(L)\,\frac{L}{4}\,\qquad 0<\alpha(L)<1 \,.$$
Estimating $\alpha$, which is the correction due the rounding down by `Floor[]` in the sum, is tricky because it oscillates.
I tweaked it for $L$ up to $10\,000$.
There's a slight divergence as $L$ increases to $20\,000$.
One can see that $\alpha$ depends on the binary expansions of $2^{k/7}$, $k=1,\dots,6$; and there may be other number theory that can be brought to bear on the problem, but I'm rusty at it.

If people want to play with it, here's a more efficient way to compute `f[L]`:

```
ClearAll[sf1, f1];
sf1[L_Integer?Negative] = 0;
sf1[1] = 0;
sf1["limit"] = 1;
sf1["limit", L_] /; sf1["limit"] >= L := True;
sf1["limit", L_] := (Do[sf1[LL], {LL, sf1["limit"], L - 1}]; 
   sf1["limit"] = Max[sf1["limit"], L - 1]; True);
mem : sf1[L_Integer] := 
  mem = sf1[L - 1] + (1/4*Floor@(L - 1 + 300*Power[2, (L - 1)/7]));
f1[L_Integer?Positive] /; sf1["limit", L] := Floor@sf1[L];
```

The fancy sum-limit voodoo is because there is a recursion limit. Without the trickery, you could not compute `f1[L]` for `L` greater than the previous largest `L` by 1022 or more. But as far as efficiency, `f1[10000]` computes all values for `L` up to `10000` in a millisecond or two longer than it takes `f[10000]` to compute just one value.  Even if one memoizes the results of `f` with

```
mem : f[L_] := 
  mem = Floor@(1/4*Sum[Floor@(n + 300*Power[2, n/7]), {n, 1, L - 1}])
```

it still takes ~900 sec. to compute the rest of `f[L]`, `0 < L < 10000`. And for `L` up to `100000`, `f1` finishes in two seconds, whereas `f` would take nearly a day (I estimate).

Comment: This is actually great, it is only off by one at most for values of L between 1 and 99, i chose this as the accepted answer as this is far shorter & easier to evaluate compared to the solution in the previous accepted answer
My goal is to still get the error rate to below 1, but even this is really good.

Comment: @Suic Thanks. It's ok to wait a while before accepting, since marking it as accepted makes it look like there's no point in even reading the question.. We used to advise people to wait 24 hrs so that everyone around the world could get a chance. There may be experts who can give even better answers.

Comment: ah yeah ur right, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

I would fit it to a polynomial and check the difference.  Below I fit it to a 20-degree poly.  The difference between actual and fit is less than 0.6 for all values in range $1<n<99$:

```
   ClearAll[fFit, vals]
f[L_] := Floor[1/4*Sum[Floor[n + 300*Power[2, n/7]], {n, 1, L - 1}]];
nMax = 99;
vals = Table[{n, f[n]}, {n, 1, nMax}];
p1 = ListPlot[vals]
fFit[x_] = Fit[vals, Table[x^n, {n, 0, 20}], x];
p2 = Plot[fFit, {x, 0, nMax}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plots = Show[{p1, p2}, PlotLabel -> Style["Fit", 16, Bold, Black]];
difTable = 
 Table[{n, Abs[(fFit[n]) - vals[[n, 2]]]}, {n, 1, Length@vals}]
GraphicsRow[{plots, 
  ListPlot[difTable, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Difference", 16, Bold, Black]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does that mean that the difference is less than 0.6% or 0.6 literally?

Comment: @Suic, check code:  Checking absolute value of the difference of fit function and actual value

Comment: sorry, but i only started with Mathematica today so im still learning, how exactly does the fit function work? i can see that it generates a Table but what i'd need is a closed-form solution so i would want to directly compute the result of the fit function if possible (by closed form as i mentioned in the comments of the question i mean a direct computation, i.e not iterating from 1 to L - 1 or first generating a table using that function)

Comment: @Suic< ok I changed to code to explicitly define the fit function as fFit[x] so for example you can then compute fFit[35] which is equal to 22406.1 and then compare it to the value of f[35]=22406 so difference is 0.1.  Keep in mind now that the function fFit is a 20-degree polynomial and doesn't compute the table.

Comment: @Suic:  Also, whenever you need to know details of a function, type in say Fit, then hover over it, select the "I" and then review the details.  I believe it's a least-square fit but not sure.

Comment: But fFit still uses a table(unless i am misunderstanding something) what i need is a direct / closed-form equation that either gives me the exact solution or an approximation where the error rate is less than 1
An example of what i mean: f[L_]:=Floor[(75 (-2^(1/7) + 2^(L/7)))/(-1 + 2^(1/7)) + 1000/8071*(-1 + L) L] (credit to Mariusz Iwaniuk for providing this in the comments of the question) this is a direct equation that doesn't use a table or iterate from 1 to L - 1 like the original equation (which is exactly what i want) unfortunately the error margin is   up to 3, but i need it to be < 1

Comment: @Suic. You can extract formula: `g[L_] := Rationalize[(fFit /. x -> L), 0]; g[L]`

Comment: Thank you @MariuszIwaniuk but is it possible to get the formula in evaluated form? what i mean is instead of 400869731/5306957 i would want the result of 400869731/5306957 which would be 75.5366458 and so on for others.
Edit: i checked the documentation of Rationalize, and i figured that i just need to remove it and only keep the rest.

Comment: If you use `Round[fFit[n]]`, the residuals are 0 most of the time and 1 just for 3 values.

Comment: Using $AIC$ or $AIC_c$ to estimate the polynomial order gives $n=15$ as the best fit (with only two values of `Round[fFit[n]]` being off by 1 with the rest 0.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that L is a a positive Integer 1<=L<=99. Then for a specific L the expression is easily calculated:

```
f[L_]:=Floor[1/4*Sum[Floor[n+300*Power[2,n/7]],{n,1,L-1}]];
```

If you need this function many times, you may use memoization and then pre-calculate the function values:

```
f[L_]:=f[L]=Floor[1/4*Sum[Floor[n+300*Power[2,n/7]],{n,1,L-1}]];

Do[f[i],{i,1,99}]
```

If you now look at f, you see that it is defined for all integers in range:

[image]

....

Answer (score 1):

You need square brackets:

`f[L_]:=Floor[1/4*Sum[Floor[n+300*Power[2,n/7]],{n,1,L-1}]];`

Then do this:

`Table[f[L],{L,1,99}]`

Comment: ah yeah i used paranthesis instead of square brackets for the inner floor by mistake.
However this just gives me an array of outputs for L in the range of 1-99, what i want is a closed form solution or a better approximation than above for the function.

Comment: You explicitly restricted `L` to be between 1 and 99. Can you be more precise then about which `L` you are interested in? All positive integers?

Comment: Ideally i would like it to work for all positive integers yes, however my real input is most likely going to be between 1 and 99

Comment: I am not sure what more you can ask for (from a practical perspective) then the explicit list of 99 numbers (no approx involved)? You just have to run the computation once, store the result in an array, and look up the result whenever needed ( in case your main concern is speed).

Comment: Yeah i understand that, but as i said in the comments(of the question) i am simply curious whether it is possible to compute directly(which is what i meant by a closed-form solution) instead of iterating from 1 to L - 1